# how to get more than 100 rows in my jtable?

Tags: java, jtable, java-io

how to make Jtable read more than 100 rows?

 
I need to know how I can make a next and previous button for my Jtable to get data from the text file.
the code that I've made can only read the first 100 lines from my file.

the code of my button that I use to refresh my Jtable is

```
 try {
        for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) { //initializing row
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) { //initializing column
                jTable1.setValueAt(null, r, c);
            }
        }

        BufferedReader rdfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));

        String[] item = new String[100];
        String[] temp;

        int x = 0;  //read item
        while ((item[x] = rdfile.readLine()) != null) {
            temp = item[x].split("\t");
            jTable1.setValueAt((1000 + x + 1), x, 0);
            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                jTable1.setValueAt(temp[j - 1], x, j);
            }

            x++;
        }
        rdfile.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

I want to make a "next" button to view the next 100 data from the file
[image: look at the limit " I have more than 400 items and it shows only 100]

look at the limit " I have more than 400 items and it shows only 100

these are the imports i've used

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
```

please explain as if i'm a dummy in java

Comment: You could derive your own `TableModel` from `AbstractTableModel`. On model changes (growth) you would need to fire events with the `fire...` methods, so the JTable knows to adapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean but you can create a variable that holds the number of the page.

```
    int page = 1;
    for (int r = 0; r < 100 * page; r++) { //initializing row
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) { //initializing column
            jTable1.setValueAt(null, r, c);
        }
    }
```

by pressing the button you could increment or decrement the page so page would render the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Add your data in a `DefaultTableModel` then set it as the model for the `JTable`.